# What must be done to guarantee continued IP address ownership?

Tags: networking, ip-address

There is a *pretty* high-level of guarantee that we can have **continued** possession of  a **chosen** domain name as long as we renew it from our registrar (and provided that our registrar is not corrupted/incompetent).

For example, if we purchase a domain name my-domain-name.com and pay our annual renewal fees on time, it's unlikely that we will lose ownership of the domain name in the future.

**Is there such a guarantee for continued possession of IP addresses?**

For example, [*someone*](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) has publicly stated that the **specific** IP addresses  8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 belongs to him. Then, what are the necessary steps *he* must take to ensure that these addresses continue to belong to him in the future?

How much "guarantee" does future IP address ownership has?

Comment: @DavidPostill, No it's not a duplicate. That is asking for owning a random IP address, while this is asking for owning a specific **chosen** IP address into the future. It's a completely different level altogether.

Comment: It is a duplicate. The only way to own an IP address or block of IP addresses is to buy a block and register it.

Comment: @DavidPostill, That's where you are wrong. IP addresses aren't chosen but **assigned** to registered members of RIR.

Comment: Exactly. It's assigned until it's unassigned. There are strict rules regarding this process (although mistakes do happen). Nothing is guaranteed 100%. "There are a number of ways that previously issued number resources can come back to ARIN. IP addresses or AS numbers may be revoked for nonpayment of fees, they may be voluntarily returned by the holder, or they may be reclaimed by ARIN in instances of confirmed fraudulent activity or abandonment of resources."

Comment: @DavidPostill, Nonpayment of fees, and fraudulent activity are also reasons for reclaiming domain names hence they are taken for granted by the context of the question. The question contrasts domain name registration with IP address registration. How much "guarantee" does IP address ownership has?  What are these strict rules which governs the process? What are the necessary steps he must take to ensure that these addresses continue to belong to him in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How much "guarantee" does future IP address ownership have?

> What are these strict rules which governs the process?
>
> What are the necessary steps he must take to ensure that these addresses continue to belong to him in the future?**

Using [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/) as an example:

> [8. Transfers](https://www.arin.net/policy/nrpm.html#eight)
>
> It should be understood that number resources are not 'sold' under
> ARIN administration. Rather, number resources are assigned to an
> organization for its exclusive use for the purpose stated in the
> request, provided the terms of the **Registration Services Agreement**
> continue to be met and the stated purpose for the number resources
> remains the same. Number resources are administered and assigned
> according to ARIN's published policies.

So the holder has to meet the terms of the **Registration Services Agreement**.

The ARIN **Registration Services Agreement** can be seen https://www.arin.net/resources/agreements/rsa.pdf:

> Subject to Holder’s on going compliance with its obligations under the
> Service Terms, including, without limitation, the payment of the fees
> (as set forth in Section 4), ARIN shall (i) provide the Services to
> Holder in accordance with the Service Terms and (ii) grant to Holder
> the following specified rights:
>
> - (1) **The exclusive right to be the registrant of the Included Number Resources within the ARIN database**;
> - (2) The right to use the Included Number Resources within the ARIN database; and
> - (3) The right to transfer the registration of the Included Number Resources pursuant to the Policies.

It also says:

> 7. NO PROPERTY RIGHTS Holder acknowledges and agrees that: (a) the number resources are not property (real, personal, or intellectual) of
>    Holder; (b) Holder does not and will not have or acquire any property
>    rights in or to any number resources for any reason, including but not
>    limited to, by virtue of this Agreement or the prior issuance of any
>    number resources to it or any access or use thereof by Holder; (c)
>    Holder will not attempt, directly or indirectly, to obtain or assert
>    any patent, trademark, service mark, copyright, or any other form of
>    intellectual, propr ietary, or property rights in any number resources
>    in the United States or any other country; and (d) Holder will
>    transfer or receive number resources in accordance with the Policies.

You can read the rest of the Agreement for all the fine details...

There is also a [Registration Services Agreement (RSA) FAQ](https://www.arin.net/resources/agreements/rsa_faq.html).

Comment: Is it true that the conclusion is "Once 8.8.8.8 has been assigned to someone, it's trivial for them to continue keeping it as long as they do not breach the terms, as they have already received the exclusive right to the database entry, That even if another company offers the RIR $10b in exchange of the *slot* to 8.8.8.8, the RIR cannot accept the *bribe* due to the contract"?

Comment: "ARIN believes that section 14(k) provides a fair, effective, and relatively low cost means of resolving any disputes. To date, it has never been used, but remains available if needed by either party."

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to domain names, this is not a very clear situation, even if it represents de facto permanent ownership. An interesting read here: ["Property Rights in IPv4 Numbers: Recognizing a New Form of Intellectual Property"](http://www.americanbar.org/publications/blt/2012/11/03_rubi.html)

Comment: I'll accept this as answer until a better answer comes along. Regretted not asking this on serverfault.com though, as the folks here aren't the target audience with the  expertise to properly answer this question.